# What software is appropriate for professional game or animation 3d models?

Tags: 3d, animation, modeling

I'm learning how to make 3D animation (I know that one person can't do much in this topic but I want to give a try).

I have been keen on it for 1-2 years, but I have been started doing it seriously a few months ago.

Is it possible for me (one-person team) using programs like Blender etc. to make something like this:

[image]

or this:[image]

I'm quite talented in art and this stuff but I'm having doubts if it's reachable level for me. That's why I'm asking. Maybe Maya can do the trick.

Comment: is it possible? yes. It's not about software tricks, it's about mastering the technique.

Comment: This is an excellent head modeling tutorial if you decide you still want to do this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xls25e08sSg

Topology matters when you are just modeling heads in a 3D package like Blender, unwrapping or doing things for games or when you need to animate. It doesn't matter if you're just sculpting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

You can create any level of detail, what maters is your modeling skill and your familiarity with the software.

You can create some amazing things with [Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6MlUcmOul8&index=7&list=PL6B3937A5D230E335) and even [Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXI0l3yqBrA)

Yes some programs can perform some functions better than others but there is no team that doesn't use a bunch of software programs to achieve a final result.

The last picture you reference is certainly not done all in one program. Probably Maya for rigging, Zbrush for modeling, maybe Rhino for textures.

The bottom line is use what you are familiar with/have access to, work on fundamentals of modeling and worry about the software later.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer. I have very little rank so I cannot upvote it but of course I'm accepting it.

Comment: Glad to help! Keep practicing!

Comment: Ovaryraptor is correct, if you want a very professional learning course (and willing to spend $30 or so) I would recommend CG Cookie. They show how to use Blender and Unity together. https://www.cgcookie.com/course/modeling-realistic-characters-with-blender

Answer (score 0):

Blender is open-source and freeware, and though there **are** a *lot* of competing high dollar value DCCs out there, it's worth remembering that Blender is actually used in a fair few pipelines in studios, because it's powerful, it works, and it often has newly developed tools and idea before some of the paid DCC apps.

That said, I myself *don't* use Blender much, I use modo as my DCC of choice - and for advanced texturing when I need super high detail beyond what I can do in modo and/or Affinity Photo or Photoshop, I go to Allegorithmic's Substance Painter.

Yes, you can achieve that quality of work yourself, without a team - just takes time, patience and acquiring skill.